# Uglify unexpectedly changes Angularjs code load order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-usemin, grunt-contrib-uglify

My Angular 1 code works fine in development. But when I compress my Angular project to **dist** with Grunt, my directives run before my services and app.run(), which results in breaking the page.

I traced the issue to **uglify** which changes the code execution order. I don't know how to prevent my uglify from changing the execution order.

Comment: I read your answer to a below post. Why is the excution order important? Perhaps you should check if you can fix the code so it's not dependant on the order angular loads directives etc?

Comment: The directives depend on variable in a service. this service triggers in App.run() function, that is at the start of the app. Uglify pushes this function below the directive. That's the issue

Answer (score 1):

Below solution worked for me. May be this will help you too. I refered it from [here](http://mathieuhicauber-java.blogspot.in/2013/12/grunt-uglify-task-breaks-angular-app.html).

Three solutions:

- Make the grunt task do not include unwanted files, and include those files already minified in your app.
- If problem still occurs after first solution, your angular modules are not "uglify friendly". There's a special way to declare your dependencies so that minifying goes smooth, as described on this page ("a note on minification" paragraph) for example. Please note that instead of doing this declaration "by hand", you can use the "ng-min" task that automatize the process and keep your code clean.
- Well, in my case I still had issue, so I ended turning off the "mangle" option in uglify (that very option that make long strings into smaller to compress response size). You can turn off the option like this :

  ```
  uglify: {
      options: {
         mangle: false
      },
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But my issue is not because of the injection. Its the order of execution. Directives goes to top before everything.